# How do I convert SQL getdate() function into a string in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Tags: sql-server

How do I convert SQL getdate() function into a string in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try:

```
select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),103)
```

There's more info on the different conversion codes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: Thanks I was just looking at a clean way to do this.  That worked.

Comment: In case someone gets confused using a format that returns a longer string, the `varchar(10)` is going to truncate your string. You can do the following to avoid this: `CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 21)`.

Answer (score 5):

Use conversion code [103](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
convert(varchar, getdate(), 103)
```

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me

```
replace(convert(char(11),getdate(),113),' ','-')
```

Comment: Please go through the Question before answering. Your answer doesn't seem to provide the correct answer.